# Child element namespace overridden by the root element namespace in JIBX

Tags: jibx

I am getting below exception at runtime while unmarshalling response xml using jibx.

My root level binding has the namespace as 'abc.com/' but the child element tag has 
different namespace as xyz.com. During unmarshalling root level mapping element namespace is overridden for the child element namespace.
below is the definition I added in the binding xml for the element tag.

`<value style="element" name="ipName" get-method="getIpName" set-method="setIpName" ns="https://xyz.coms" />`

Exception:
`org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: Expected "{abc.com/}ipName" start tag, found "{xyz.com/}ipName"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bale to resolve this error. Here I got the answer 
http://marc.info/?l=jibx-users&m=122091431913533&q=raw.

Just added separate mapping for the child element.